# Cannot play after pausing tvOS (TVML/TVJS)

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I am developing a tvml/tvjs application and I have added the following code to allow audio to play in the background (applicationDidBecomeActive):

```
 let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

 do {
     try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
     try audioSession.setActive(true)
 } catch {
     print("no audio to assign")
 }
```

I also set the first item in `Required Background Modes` in info.plist to `App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay`.

My problem now is that although I can play audio in the background and pause the audio from anywhere in tvOS, I cannot play the audio after pausing. I am looking for the functionality like the Podcast app where I can freely play and pause the current streaming audio.

I cannot seem to find anything in the documentation for TVML/TVJS that points me in the right direction. Thanks!